# Is it possible to avoid CASE ... WHEN in generate_series statement when two different beginning dates are required

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, generate-series

I have one query that I use for different date sequence generation depending on the query parameters from the backend.

Gist for it is that for the first month, I need `date` to be `generate_series` input date and for the rest of the generated months' `date` should be the beginning of the month as shown in the results below.

Here are the three ways, how I use it below with the correct results.

Example for month sequence ->

```
    SELECT
        date::DATE AS sequence_value,
        CASE WHEN date = '2022-01-16'
            THEN date::DATE
            ELSE date_trunc('MONTH', date)::DATE END AS date,
        (DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH')::DATE AS date_end,
        to_char(date, 'MONTH') AS name
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2022-01-16', '2023-01-02', INTERVAL '1 MONTH') AS date

RESULTS:

"sequence_value"    "date"       "date_end"       "name"
"2022-01-16"    "2022-01-16"    "2022-02-01"    "JANUARY  "
"2022-02-16"    "2022-02-01"    "2022-03-01"    "FEBRUARY "
"2022-03-16"    "2022-03-01"    "2022-04-01"    "MARCH    "
"2022-04-16"    "2022-04-01"    "2022-05-01"    "APRIL    "
```

Example for week sequence ->

```
    SELECT
        date::DATE AS sequence_value,
        CASE WHEN date = '2022-01-16'
            THEN date::DATE
            ELSE date_trunc('WEEK', date)::DATE END AS date,
        (DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', date) + INTERVAL '1 WEEK')::DATE AS date_end,
        to_char(date, 'MM-DD') AS name
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2022-01-16', '2023-01-02', INTERVAL '1 WEEK') AS date


RESULTS:


"sequence_value"    "date"       "date_end"      "name"
"2022-01-16"    "2022-01-16"    "2022-01-17"    "01-16"
"2022-01-23"    "2022-01-17"    "2022-01-24"    "01-23"
"2022-01-30"    "2022-01-24"    "2022-01-31"    "01-30"
"2022-02-06"    "2022-01-31"    "2022-02-07"    "02-06"
```

Example for day sequence ->

```
    SELECT
        date::DATE AS sequence_value,
        CASE WHEN date = '2022-01-16'
            THEN date::DATE
            ELSE date_trunc('DAY', date)::DATE END AS date,
        (DATE_TRUNC('DAY', date) + INTERVAL '1 DAY')::DATE AS date_end,
        to_char(date, 'MM-DD') AS name
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2022-01-16', '2023-01-02', INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS date

RESULTS:

"sequence_value"    "date"        "date_end"    "name"
"2022-01-16"    "2022-01-16"    "2022-01-17"    "01-16"
"2022-01-17"    "2022-01-17"    "2022-01-18"    "01-17"
"2022-01-18"    "2022-01-18"    "2022-01-19"    "01-18"
"2022-01-19"    "2022-01-19"    "2022-01-20"    "01-19"
```

Is there a way to make the query more concise and efficient?

Perhaps, it is possible to replace the CASE ... WHEN statement with something else?

As of now, I don't really need it in the day sequence generation as it generates the dates day by day, however, for the month sequence generation it is necessary, as otherwise, I would get the month starting date for the day 16th.

Comment: Use GREATEST() instead of a CASE expression? Won't change performance (and I'd suggest trying to improve performance is premature optimisation), but it does make for tidier code.

Comment: What is wrong with case?

Comment: Nothing wrong, but just interested if there are any other possibilities on how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are a couple of the ways I'd go about it...

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9H1ZAUv3)

```
SELECT
  GREATEST('2022-01-16'::date, s.date                     )   AS date_start,
  LEAST(   '2023-01-01'::date, s.date + INTERVAL '1 MONTH')   AS date_end,
  to_char(s.date, 'MONTH')                                    AS name
FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES(
    DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', '2022-01-16'::date),
                        '2023-01-01'::date - INTERVAL '1 DAY',
    INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
  )
    AS s
```

| date_start | date_end | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-16 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | JANUARY |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | FEBRUARY |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | MARCH |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | APRIL |
| 2022-05-01 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | MAY |
| 2022-06-01 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | JUNE |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | JULY |
| 2022-08-01 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | AUGUST |
| 2022-09-01 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | SEPTEMBER |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00 | OCTOBER |
| 2022-11-01 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00 | NOVEMBER |
| 2022-12-01 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | DECEMBER |

> ```
> SELECT 12
> ```

```
SELECT
  GREATEST('2022-01-16'::date, s.date)   AS date_start,
  LEAST(   '2023-01-01'::date, s.date)   AS date_end,
  to_char(m.month_start, 'MONTH')        AS name
FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES(
    '2022-01-16'::date,
    '2023-01-01'::date - INTERVAL '1 DAY',
    INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
  )
    AS s
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT
      DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', s.date)                       AS month_start,
      DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', s.date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH'  AS month_end
  )
    AS m
```

| date_start | date_end | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-16 | 2022-01-16 | JANUARY |
| 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-16 | FEBRUARY |
| 2022-03-16 | 2022-03-16 | MARCH |
| 2022-04-16 | 2022-04-16 | APRIL |
| 2022-05-16 | 2022-05-16 | MAY |
| 2022-06-16 | 2022-06-16 | JUNE |
| 2022-07-16 | 2022-07-16 | JULY |
| 2022-08-16 | 2022-08-16 | AUGUST |
| 2022-09-16 | 2022-09-16 | SEPTEMBER |
| 2022-10-16 | 2022-10-16 | OCTOBER |
| 2022-11-16 | 2022-11-16 | NOVEMBER |
| 2022-12-16 | 2022-12-16 | DECEMBER |

> ```
> SELECT 12
> ```

```
SELECT
  GREATEST('2022-01-16'::date, s.date                    )   AS date_start,
  LEAST(   '2023-01-01'::date, s.date + INTERVAL '1 WEEK')   AS date_end,
  to_char(s.date, 'MM-DD')                                   AS name
FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES(
    DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', '2022-01-16'::date),
                       '2023-01-01'::date - INTERVAL '1 DAY',
    INTERVAL '1 WEEK'
  )
    AS s
```

| date_start | date_end | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-16 | 2022-01-17 00:00:00 | 01-10 |
| 2022-01-17 | 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 01-17 |
| 2022-01-24 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 01-24 |
| 2022-01-31 | 2022-02-07 00:00:00 | 01-31 |
| 2022-02-07 | 2022-02-14 00:00:00 | 02-07 |
| 2022-02-14 | 2022-02-21 00:00:00 | 02-14 |
| 2022-02-21 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00 | 02-21 |
| 2022-02-28 | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 02-28 |
| 2022-03-07 | 2022-03-14 00:00:00 | 03-07 |
| 2022-03-14 | 2022-03-21 00:00:00 | 03-14 |
| 2022-03-21 | 2022-03-28 00:00:00 | 03-21 |
| 2022-03-28 | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 | 03-28 |
| 2022-04-04 | 2022-04-11 00:00:00 | 04-04 |
| 2022-04-11 | 2022-04-18 00:00:00 | 04-11 |
| 2022-04-18 | 2022-04-25 00:00:00 | 04-18 |
| 2022-04-25 | 2022-05-02 00:00:00 | 04-25 |
| 2022-05-02 | 2022-05-09 00:00:00 | 05-02 |
| 2022-05-09 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00 | 05-09 |
| 2022-05-16 | 2022-05-23 00:00:00 | 05-16 |
| 2022-05-23 | 2022-05-30 00:00:00 | 05-23 |
| 2022-05-30 | 2022-06-06 00:00:00 | 05-30 |
| 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-13 00:00:00 | 06-06 |
| 2022-06-13 | 2022-06-20 00:00:00 | 06-13 |
| 2022-06-20 | 2022-06-27 00:00:00 | 06-20 |
| 2022-06-27 | 2022-07-04 00:00:00 | 06-27 |
| 2022-07-04 | 2022-07-11 00:00:00 | 07-04 |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-07-18 00:00:00 | 07-11 |
| 2022-07-18 | 2022-07-25 00:00:00 | 07-18 |
| 2022-07-25 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | 07-25 |
| 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-08 00:00:00 | 08-01 |
| 2022-08-08 | 2022-08-15 00:00:00 | 08-08 |
| 2022-08-15 | 2022-08-22 00:00:00 | 08-15 |
| 2022-08-22 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 | 08-22 |
| 2022-08-29 | 2022-09-05 00:00:00 | 08-29 |
| 2022-09-05 | 2022-09-12 00:00:00 | 09-05 |
| 2022-09-12 | 2022-09-19 00:00:00 | 09-12 |
| 2022-09-19 | 2022-09-26 00:00:00 | 09-19 |
| 2022-09-26 | 2022-10-03 00:00:00 | 09-26 |
| 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-10 00:00:00 | 10-03 |
| 2022-10-10 | 2022-10-17 00:00:00 | 10-10 |
| 2022-10-17 | 2022-10-24 00:00:00 | 10-17 |
| 2022-10-24 | 2022-10-31 00:00:00 | 10-24 |
| 2022-10-31 | 2022-11-07 00:00:00 | 10-31 |
| 2022-11-07 | 2022-11-14 00:00:00 | 11-07 |
| 2022-11-14 | 2022-11-21 00:00:00 | 11-14 |
| 2022-11-21 | 2022-11-28 00:00:00 | 11-21 |
| 2022-11-28 | 2022-12-05 00:00:00 | 11-28 |
| 2022-12-05 | 2022-12-12 00:00:00 | 12-05 |
| 2022-12-12 | 2022-12-19 00:00:00 | 12-12 |
| 2022-12-19 | 2022-12-26 00:00:00 | 12-19 |
| 2022-12-26 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 12-26 |

> ```
> SELECT 51
> ```